# CPU Speed drops while running Cinebench but temp drops too

Tags: macbook-pro, performance, cpu

I've been noticing that my MacBook Pro 2015 2.8 GHz is getting slower under load.  So I ran some tests.

I run Cinebench R20 and get a value of 1370.

When I attach peripherals I get odd results.  Adding an external monitor, TB2 to ethernet and a USB HD causes the test to drop to 1033.

Watching the test while having Intel Power Gadget running shows that the CPU drops to 1.9 GHz or less.  I'd expect this to be heat related but the temps drop as well, down to about 80C. I do notice that the power draw starts dropping on the core, but I don't know why this is occurring. Any ideas on how to keep the CPU speeds up?

[image: Intel Power Gadget while running Cinebench]

It gets worse when playing Elder Scrolls Online, CPU drops down to 1.4 GHz can be seen with no overheating occurring.  This is without any peripherals attached.

And an hour later I ran the Cinebench test again and got this:

[image: really bad cpu]

Comment: It could be Apple's way of reducing battery usage. I have no idea if Apple even does this, just a guess.

Comment: @At0mic this is new behaviour, so don't think its an Apple thing